# Sort costum NSMutableArray by a certain field

Tags: objective-c

I have `NSMutableArray` of costume objects  each called `*object` .
Than, each array has a `NSString` field called color : `object.color`
I need to arrange the array according to certain color, for example put the reds first , than the rest of the colors in any random sort.

I know how to sort the array according to field, but i need to sort it according to certain color.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"color" ascending:TRUE];
    [self.tasks sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

this just take the objects with a certain random color, and put it to be first, but i can't control the specific color ..

**EDIT**

example :

```
array objects now :
object1.color=@"red"
object2.color=@"orange"
object3.color=@"blue"
object4.color=@"red"
object5.color=@"orange"


array looks like this after sort to red :
object1.color=@"red"
object4.color=@"red"
object2.color=@"orange"
object5.color=@"orange"
object3.color=@"blue"
```

Comment: They are called `*object`?  I don't think so.

Comment: Your question is to sort on NSColor values?

Comment: Put another field just for the sort descriptor to use. How do you expect it to sort it by color names, I don't understand..

Comment: they don't called objects its just an example , and they are not nscolor but string with colors name- i made .

Comment: see edit of the question

Comment: questions on how to sort NSArray's are littered throughout stackoverflow. The same answer that you have accepted below is the same answer as many questions. Please put in some level of effort into solving these issues yourself

Comment: I wonder what is so bad about this question, i think its very relevant to everybody , even if i write colors and not colours

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started, but you don't define how you specify "the red colors" (or even how the colours are specified), so I've just assumed they are called `@"Red"`.  You can fill-in the gaps.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSString *colour1 = [(Object *)a color];
    NSString *colour2 = [(Object *)b color];
    BOOL firstRed = [colour1 isEqualToString:@"Red"];
    BOOL secondRed = [colour2 isEqualToString:@"Red"];
    if (firstRed && secondRed)
        return NSOrderedSame;
    else if (firstRed)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (secondRed)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    return [colour1 compare:colour2];
}];
```

**EDIT** As pointed out by @MartinR, we want to return `NSOrderedSame` if both colours are `@"Red"` to make the implementation correct.

Comment: check my edit of the question please, and let me know if its still your answer. thanks a lot .

Comment: @Curnelious I would expect that to be something you can decide for yourself.

Comment: thanks. i am not sure i got your answer yet .. you compare 2 colors, i need to take all objects with field color.red and put them first in the array ..

Comment: @Curnelious I know.  Please take the time to understand the method (and similar methods) presented in my answer.  The string literal I use is wrong and the cast of the `a` and `b` to `Object *` is probably not needed.  However I would like **you** to take the valuable stuff from my answer and apply it to your project.  This is what programmers do.  I also use the correct spelling of "colour" ;-)

Comment: I still don't understand your answer , although i am doing what "programmers do" for a few years. maybe i am not that good, but i still don't understand the answer . i hope i deserved to understand it even that English is not my first language ..

Comment: @Curnelious OK, well the `[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]` method will be called multiple times for objects within the array to decide the order of the sort.  The comparator I present makes `@"Red"` *worth more* than other colour string names, hence it will be pushed closer to the front of the sorted array.

Comment: ohh ok, now i can imagine it, each value is going up/down according to its color value . thanks.

Comment: @Curnelious To be more precise the block passed to `[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]` will be called multiple times, not the method itself.

Comment: yes i know blocks, i just couldn't imagine the sorting method, now i see the logics .

Comment: How do you know when its done to sort the relevant array according to the new nsarray ?

Comment: @Curnelious It's done when the call to `[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]` returns.

Comment: ok thanks (i can't understand how to check when its done but i will explore and find by myself)

Comment: Shouldn't the comparator return `NSOrderedSame` if both colours(!) are "Red"?

Comment: @MartinR Actually you are right!  I will edit my answer!  Cheers.